# I can't understand this: You wouldn’t have to spout embarrassing platitude in public

Tags: phrases, expressions

I was watching a movie in which this conversation happened in a bar:

> **Person 1:** You wouldn’t have to spout embarrassing platitude in public.
>   **Person 2:** The fact is I won't spout platitude much longer.

What does this mean?

Comment: What did looking the words up in a dictionary tell you? And what are you still unsure of after having looked up the words?

Comment: What I get from that is something like : you don't need to utter useless words, not sure about this as it doesn't have any connection to their conversation

Comment: I doubt that the quote is precise, and even if it is it lacks enough context to interpret reliably.

Comment: Can we see the that conversation it doesn't seem to have any connection to? :)

Comment: I found this on the internet : If you wrote down all these business lessons, then you wouldn't have to spout embarrassing platitudes in public. That's the conversation's first part. Looks like she babbled irrrelevant words in public where she was supposed to present something relevant but she is confident she won't do it from now on.

Comment: I doubt this is transcribed correctly. What was the movie?

Comment: It seems it's from an episode of _Girls_ called “She Said OK” (season 3, episode 3). [This page](http://www.styleite.com/tv/girls-season-3-episode-3/) describes the exchange of words in more detail—it seems Marius' guess that Person 2 (Hermie) is dying was accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult guess, without background or context. Stil, try these:

Person 1: **If that [whatever event] happens,** the reason for your talking nonsense would disappear.

Person 2: Well, I am leaving anyway, so I won't be around talking nonsense anymore.

or:

Person 1: Really, you don't have any reasons to talk nonsense.

Person 2: Well, I am /leaving anyway/perhaps dying??/, so I won't be around to talk nonsense anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I found this on the internet : If you wrote down all these business lessons, then you wouldn't have to spout embarrassing platitudes in public.

That's the conversation's first part.

Looks like she babbled irrrelevant words in public where she was supposed to present something relevant but she is confident she won't do it from now on.

Comment: Where on the Internet?